# Intercept key press delete

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview in my users component. On listview property LabelEdit is true. On listview i have contextmenustrip with item Delete with shortcut key Del. How can i catch key press Del that if a cell is edited - delete the text in the cell, if is not editable - delete Item on Listview???

Comment: [What have you tired?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Specifically, have you tried registering event handlers? Also, is this Windows Forms or WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start simple with binding to the `KeyDown` (or `KeyUp`) event on the `ListView`:

```
listView1.KeyDown += listView1_KeyDown;
```

And then in the event:

```
void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        // Check if selected item is editable and act accordingly...

        // Bypass the control's default handling; 
        // otherwise, remove to pass the event to the default control handler.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```